# relative time on grafana dashboard/panel keeps getting overridden by dashboard time range

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am having trouble with setting up a panel that shouldn't include the time range set for the entire dashboard, but have its own time range set. From what I have read, the option to do that is in the Query Options called "relative time".

[my query with relative time set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hvT2.png)

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S4Xa.png)

It basically keeps using the 5 Minute range set on the dashboard time range.
Though, once I hit the "run queries" button, the correct panel actually shows up for like 500ms with a time range of 24 hours and then gets overriden by the dashboard time again.

[this is what shows up for like 500ms once I hit the "run queries" button (this is what i want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOWjL.png)

I'm basically trying to have a dashboard that has a stat panel which shows the current CPU usage and below I'd like to have a time range panel which shows the cpu usage from a 24 hour range.
My dashboard's refresh time is set to 5 seconds and every 5 seconds it also shows the correct panel with a time range of 24 hours but again just for like 500ms and it keeps getting overriden
to 5 minutes afterwards.

I am using Grafana 10.0.3

Comment: The option "Relative time" generally works in 10.2 (play.grafana.com). Your case might be some example of plugin interference, or maybe 10.0.3 specifically had a bug with that; consider filing an issue in grafana's repo.

Comment: @markalex you are right, I downgraded to 10.0.2 and it works perfectly fine. Thank you.

Comment: @markalex actually it might be related to something else. I can create the panel properly in other dashboards without getting the issue, but it just doesn't work in that specific dashboard. I'm still trying to figure out what it correlates to.

Comment: I just redid the dashboard by just copy pasting the panel jsons and it works fine now. not sure what the issue was.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and I managed to solve it by editing the dashboard's JSON model and changing the `.liveNow` variable to `false`.

I noticed this difference when following @sh_cy comment I created a new dashboard and the relative panel worked fine there. I compared the JSON models and saw that `.liveNow` is different, I changed it and it started to work as expected.